# Why my array of NSDictionary lost its objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsdictionary

I'm having a difficulty with this one I have a method that returns a value of Array of NSDictionary once I pass the return value of an array first it works. I already get the object in my NSLog but when I try to access the objects of my Array of NSDictionary in another method I get the error and I think that I loses the objects of the array.

Here's the method that return an Array of NSDictionary:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)selectItemDataTbl {
    NSMutableArray *l_array_data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *query = @"SELECT pid, fname, gen_name, type, fu, fprice FROM tbl_selectItem_data";
    sqlite3_stmt *l_statement;

    if (sqlite3_open([l_SqliteDb UTF8String], &(_database)) == SQLITE_OK) {
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &l_statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while(sqlite3_step(l_statement) == SQLITE_ROW){
                NSMutableDictionary *l_dataDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

                NSString *l_pid = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(l_statement, 0)];
                NSString *l_name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(l_statement, 1)];
                NSString *l_genName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(l_statement, 2)];
                NSString *l_Type = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(l_statement, 3)];
                NSString *l_u = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(l_statement, 4)];
                NSString *l_Price = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(l_statement, 5)];

                [l_dataDictionary setObject:l_pid forKey:@"pid"];
                [l_dataDictionary setObject:l_name forKey:@"name"];
                [l_dataDictionary setObject:l_genName forKey:@"genName"];
                [l_dataDictionary setObject:l_Type forKey:@"Type"];
                [l_dataDictionary setObject:l_u forKey:@"u"];
                [l_dataDictionary setObject:l_Price forKey:@"Price"];

                [l_array_data addObject:l_dataDictionary];
            }
            NSLog(@"l_array_data count: %i", [l_array_data count]);

            sqlite3_finalize(l_statement);
            sqlite3_close(_database);
        }
    }
    return  l_array_data;
}
```

And here my method how I access it I'm calling it on my viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)selectItemData {
    _l_alldataInSelectItem = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _l_prodId = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _l_prodName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _l_prodGenName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _l_prodCompType = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _l_prodUom = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _l_prodListPrice = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _l_alldataInSelectItem = [dbc selectItemDataTbl];
    _l_selectItemData_Dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    for (_l_selectItemData_Dictionary in _l_alldataInSelectItem) {
        NSString *Id =  [_l_selectItemData_Dictionary valueForKey:@"pid"] ;
        NSString *Name = [_l_selectItemData_Dictionary valueForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *GenName = [_l_selectItemData_Dictionary valueForKey:@"genName"];
        NSString *Type = [_l_selectItemData_Dictionary valueForKey:@"Type"];
        NSString *U = [_l_selectItemData_Dictionary valueForKey:@"u"];
        NSString *Price = [_l_selectItemData_Dictionary valueForKey:@"Price"];

        [_l_prodId addObject:Id];
        [_l_prodName addObject:Name];
        [_l_prodGenName addObject:GenName];
        [_l_prodCompType addObject:GenName];
        [_l_prodUom addObject:U];
        [_l_prodListPrice addObject:Price];
    }
    NSLog(@"adsfasdf %@", _l_prodId);
    NSLog(@"adsfasdf %i", [_l_alldataInSelectItem count]);
}
```

But in this method I can't get the value of my array _l_alldataInSelectItem

```
- (void)textFieldshouldChange {
    NSString *searchKey = self.txt_SearchField.text;
    NSMutableArray *searchingData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (![searchKey isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSLog(@"When TextField text is changed, this will be called");
        NSLog(@"textFieldshouldChange _l_alldataInSelectItem: %i", [_l_alldataInSelectItem count]);
    }
}
```

here's how i declare my l_alldataInSelectItem. I declared it on my header file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *l_alldataInSelectItem, *l_prodId, *l_prodName, *l_prodGenName, *l_prodCompType, *l_prodUom, *l_prodListPrice;
```

Comment: You don't give us a clue as to how `_l_alldataInSelectItem` is declared/allocated.

Comment: @HotLicks I've already edit my post

Comment: Try replacing references to `_l_alldataInSelectItem` with `self.l_alldataInSelectItem`. (Then run Product->Analyze to identify the memory management problems.)

Answer (score 0):

Go systematically through the possibilities.

Possibility 1: There are gremlins somewhere trying to annoy you. We exclude that.

Possibility 2: You never created the data. Set a breakpoint on the return statement in selectItemDataTbl and check it.

Possibility 3: You never stored the array. Well, there is the fact that you store an empty mutable array into _l_alldataInSelectItem which is absolutely pointless, but set a breakpoint on the last statement in selectItemData and check it.

Possibility 4: You stored it and overwrote it. Search for all places where you store to _l_alldataInSelectItem or to a property named l_alldataInSelectItem, set breakpoints everywhere, and check.

Possibility 5 (the stupid one): _l_alldataInSelectItem is a weak instance variable or a weak property.

Possibility 6: You stored it, but looked for it in a different place. Is the self in textFieldshouldChange the same as the self in selectItemData? Set breakpoints and check.

Possibility 7: You are doing something asynchronously. The variable will be set, but much later than you think.

Most important: Put it very strongly in your mind that *you* did something wrong, and you don't have to solve any magical puzzles, all you need to do is find out what you did wrong.

Comment: You did see [Phillip Mills](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691258/why-my-array-of-nsdictionary-lost-its-objects/35827708#comment32794989_21691258) comments and NewDroidDev answer on the comment?